# How to query boost::log severity?

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log, boost-logging

I'm using trivial logging of [boost::log](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/log/doc/html/index.html) library and I want to execute some code depending on currently set logger severity. This is needed for constructing of log message only if it will be outputted. But I cannot find the right way for querying severity. The code must be something like:

```
if (boost::log::trivial::severity <=
    boost::log::trivial::severity_level::trace)
{
  // construct log message
  BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << message;
}
```

In addition may be there is some way when I know that the message will be outputted to avoid double checking of severity and output it directly instead of using `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL` macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work like that. You need to provide a filter function to boost::log::trivial as per the documentation:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/trivial_filtering.html

```
void init()
{
    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        // here they've used a constant but you could use a global or
        // a function
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}

int main(int, char*[])
{
    init();

    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

    return 0;
}
```

The object passed to `logging::core::set_filter` is of type `boost::log::filter`

You could just as easily write:

```
auto filt = logging::filter(logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info);
logging::core::get()->set_filter(filt);
```

`filt` is a lightweight function object whose job is to inspect the attributes sent to it and return whether or not all tests against those attributes return `true`. In this case there is only one test - `logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info`.

It is the job of the logger to construct the attribute set and pass it to `boost::log::core` when it wants to emit something.

The long and short of it is that you must track the logging level in your own variable. Here is one way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;


int main(int, char*[])
{
    // track your own variable here
    logging::trivial::severity_level my_log_level = logging::trivial::trace;

    // with this filter
    auto filt = logging::filter(logging::trivial::severity >= my_log_level);
    logging::core::get()->set_filter(filt);

    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

    // now you have control
    if (my_log_level <= logging::trivial::trace)
    {
        std::cout << "tracing\n";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. There must be some way to execute arbitrary code conditionally according to the severity.

Comment: Will flesh out the answer. Unfortunately you assume incorrectly

Comment: @bobeff answer updated with example of how to track your own logging level

Comment: "The long and short of it is that you must track the logging level in your own variable." This seems like working solution. 10x.

Comment: The filter copies `my_log_level`, so when you change it the filter will still use the old value. You can use `boost::phoenix::ref(my_log_level)` to make the filter refer to the variable, but you will have to ensure that the variable is accessed thread-safely.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option which adds another layer of logging macros and wraps code to be called conditionally in a lambda function fed to those macros.  The lambda function is evaluated only if the severity-level constraint is satisfied.

To the best of my understanding, this method is thread-safe, but my understanding of boost::log is...limited. I haven't tested in a multi-threaded environment.

```
 //g++ -std=gnu++11  -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK main.cpp -lboost_log -lpthread -o lambda_demo                    

 #include <boost/log/core.hpp>
 #include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
 #include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>

 namespace logging = boost::log;

 #define LOG_TRACE(ARG) BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << ARG;
 #define LOG_INFO(ARG) BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << ARG;

 const std::string complicated_function(const std::string &message)
 {
     std::cout << "\nInside complicated_function.\n" << std::flush;
     return "Returning from complicated_function (" + message + ").\n";
 }

 int main(int, char*[])
 {
     std::cout << "\n" << complicated_function("called from std::cout") << "\n" << std::flush;

     BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
     BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
     BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
     BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
     BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
     BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message\n";

     LOG_TRACE ("Coming up: a trace message with a lambda function:");

     LOG_TRACE (
         [=]() {
             return complicated_function("(called from LOG_TRACE");
         }()
         );

     logging::core::get()->set_filter
         (
             logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
             );

     BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "After setting filter, another trace severity message";
     BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "After setting filter, another debug severity message";
     BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "After setting filter, another informational severity message";
     BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "After setting filter, another warning severity message";
     BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "After setting filter, anothern error severity message";
     BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "After setting filter, another fatal severity message\n";

     LOG_TRACE ("Coming up: a trace message with a lambda function:");
     LOG_TRACE (
         [=]() {
             return complicated_function("called from LOG_TRACE");
         }()
         );

     LOG_INFO ("Coming up: an info message with a lambda function:");
     LOG_INFO (
         [=]() {
             return complicated_function("called from LOG_INFO");
         }()
         );

     return 0;
 }
```